# Scrolling delay effect slower on IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, scroll, pseudo-element

As seen on [THIS LIVE DEMO](http://germanalvarez.net/5/laboratory3.html), if you open the link from any normal browser (FF/Opera/Chrome), as you scroll the panel, blue pseudo-elements have a delay effect on their position.

Even though IE11 does apply some kind of effect on it, it seems to be several times slower than on other browsers.

This is related code on scroll effect:

```
function checkScroll(){   
      if ($('.contentPanel').attr('data-active')==="hola"){

         if ($('.contentPanel').scrollTop() >= ($('.section-adapta').position().top)-150) {
            scrolledY1=$('.contentPanel').scrollTop() - $('.section-adapta').position().top+150;
             $('.icon-adapta').css('margin-top', 10-((scrolledY1*0.1))+'px');    }

         if ($('.contentPanel').scrollTop() >= ($('.section-interac').position().top)-150) {
            scrolledY2=$('.contentPanel').scrollTop() - $('.section-interac').position().top+150;
             $('.icon-interac').css('margin-top', -30+((scrolledY2*0.07))+'px');    }

         if ($('.contentPanel').scrollTop() >= ($('.section-dinami').position().top)-150) {
            scrolledY3=$('.contentPanel').scrollTop() - $('.section-dinami').position().top+150;
             $('.icon-dinami').css('margin-top', 100-((scrolledY3*0.1))+'px');    }

         if ($('.contentPanel').scrollTop() >= ($('.section-ux').position().top)-150) {
            scrolledY4=$('.contentPanel').scrollTop() - $('.section-ux').position().top+150;
             $('.icon-ux').css('margin-top', -80+((scrolledY4*0.08))+'px');    }
       }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by different default behaviors when using `position: fixed` without setting any position (no `left`, `top`, `right` or `bottom`). The easiest way out in your case would be to use `position: absolute` instead.

Comment: I had the same problem and your answer solved it :) Thanks!